# code works fine on localhost but not on remote server php java script

Tags: javascript, php

this is my code for registering new user now i have upload my website on remote server and change the database credentials to new remote server connection. after updating new registration can not done. it shows **not inserted** in error otherwise all other query run perfectly fine on remote server.

```
<?php 
include_once '../databaseconnection.php';

$databaseconnection = new Databaseconnection();


$email_address = "";
$mobile_number = "";






$checkpostrequest = ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST");

if($checkpostrequest)

{
    $error = false;

    $erromessage = "";

$errordupchk = false;
$erromessagedup = "";





if(isset($_POST['email_address']))
{
    $emailchk="select id from user where email='".$_POST['email_address']."'";
  $emailchkexe=mysqli_query($databaseconnection->databaselink,$emailchk);

  $emailchk_fromsuperadmintable ="select id from super_admin where admin_email='".$_POST['email_address']."'";
  $emailchk_fromsuperadmintableexe=mysqli_query($databaseconnection->databaselink,$emailchk_fromsuperadmintable);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($emailchkexe)>0  || mysqli_num_rows($emailchk_fromsuperadmintableexe)>0) {

    $erromessagedup.='<li>This email id is already registered with us .</li>';

    $errordupchk=true;
  }
}



if(isset($_POST['mobile_number']))
{
    $mobilechk="select id from user where mobile='".$_POST['mobile_number']."'";
    $mobilechkexe=mysqli_query($databaseconnection->databaselink,$mobilechk);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($mobilechkexe)>0) {

    $erromessagedup.='<li>This mobile number is already registered with us .</li>';

    $errordupchk=true;
  }
}




    if(empty($_POST['email_address']))

            {

                $erromessage .= "<li>Email Address field should not be blank.</li>";

                $error = true;

            }

            if(!empty($_POST['email_address']))
                {
                    if (!filter_var($_POST['email_address'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true)
                    {

                        $erromessage .= "<li>Please enter proper Email Address.</li>";

                        $error = true;

                    }
                }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))

            {

                $erromessage .= "<li>Password field should not be blank.</li>";

                $error = true;

            }

    if(empty($_POST['con_password']))

            {

                $erromessage .= "<li>Password Confirmation field should not be blank.</li>";

                $error = true;

            }

    if(!empty($_POST['email_address']) && !empty($_POST['confirm_email']))
            {
            if($_POST['password']!=$_POST['con_password'])

                        {

                            $erromessage .= "<li>Password do not be match.</li>";

                            $error = true;

                        }
            }

    if(empty($_POST['mobile_number']))

            {

                $erromessage .= "<li>Mobile number field should not be blank.</li>";

                $error = true;

            }




    if(empty($_POST['check']))

            {

                $erromessage .= "<li>Please tick the check box.</li>";

                $error = true;

            }








if(!$errordupchk)

                {
        if(!$error)

            {

                $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($databaseconnection->databaselink,$_POST['email_address']);

                $mobile_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($databaseconnection->databaselink,$_POST['mobile_number']);

                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($databaseconnection->databaselink,$_POST['password']);

                $mobile_verify   = "NO";



                $insertquery = "INSERT INTO user (email, password, mobile, mobile_verify)
VALUES ('$email_address', '$password', '$mobile_number', '$mobile_verify')";

                $insertqueryexe = mysqli_query($databaseconnection->databaselink,$insertquery);
                if ($insertqueryexe)
                {



                    $ran_var_frm_fir_form=mt_rand(100000,1000000);
                    $_SESSION['otp_first']=$ran_var_frm_fir_form;
                    $mobile_no=$mobile_number;  


                                         /*Send SMS using PHP*/    

                    //Your authentication key
                    $authKey = "110008AaxKKSVs576d5f30";

                    //Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
                    $mobileNumber = $mobile_no;

                    //Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
                    $senderId = "grbbiz";

                    //Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.
                    $message = urlencode("Your one time password for www.grabbizz.com is".$_SESSION['otp_first'].".Thank you for registering with us.Please make sure you do not share this password with anyone.");

                    //Define route 
                    $route = "4";
                    //Prepare you post parameters
                    $postData = array(
                        'authkey' => $authKey,
                        'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
                        'message' => $message,
                        'sender' => $senderId,
                        'route' => $route
                    );

                    //API URL
                    $url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";

                    // init the resource
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                        CURLOPT_POST => true,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
                        //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
                    ));


                    //Ignore SSL certificate verification
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


                    //get response
                    $output = curl_exec($ch);

                    //Print error if any
                    if(curl_errno($ch))
                    {
                        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
                    }

                    curl_close($ch);

                    //echo $output;






                    $getid="select id from user where email='".$email_address."'";
                    $getidfetch = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($databaseconnection->databaselink,$getid));
                    $_SESSION['regid']=$getidfetch->id;
                    $response = array();
                    $response['successvalue'] = true;
                    $response['responsemessage'] = $erromessage;
                    header('Content-type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
                else
                {
                    $response = array();
                    $response['successvalue'] = false;
                    $response['responsemessage'] = "not inserted";
                    header('Content-type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }

            }

        else

            {



                $response = array();
                $response['successvalue'] = false;
                $response['responsemessage'] = $erromessage;
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($response);

                //header('location:../index.php');

            }


            }

            else
            {
                $response = array();
                $response['successvalue'] = false;
                $response['loginask'] = true;
                $response['responsemessage'] = $erromessagedup;
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($response);
            }


}




 ?>
```

this is java script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$( "input[name='tinsignup']" ).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $( "#signbut" ).trigger( "click" );
    }
});
$( "input[name='passsignup']" ).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $( "#signbut" ).trigger( "click" );
    }
});




  $(".regbutton").click(function(){
    $("#validationmessages").html('');
    $("#validationmessages").removeAttr("class","alert alert-danger");
    });
    $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
        //$("#validationmessages").hide();
        //event.preventDefault();
        //$("#validationmessages").attr("class","alert alert-warning");
          $("#validationmessages").html("<img src='img/Preloader_11.gif' alt='loading'/> <b>Please wait...</b>");
          //setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessages').fadeOut();} , 4000);
          //$("#validationmessages").show();
          var dataStringreg =  $("#indexpageform").serialize();          
       $.ajax({     
         url:"processing/indexformprocessiog.php",
           type:"POST",
           dataType:"json",
           data:dataStringreg,
           cache: false, 
           success: function(response)
       {
       if(response.successvalue)
       {

        $("#validationmessages").attr("class","alert alert-success");
        $("#validationmessages").html("<i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-fw fa-lg'></i><ul>"+response.responsemessage+"</ul>");
        setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessages').fadeOut();} , 1000);
        window.location='verify.php';

       }
       else
       {
        $("#validationmessages").html('');
        $("#validationmessages").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
        $("#validationmessages").html("<ul>"+response.responsemessage+"</ul>");
        $('#validationmessages').fadeIn();
        if (response.loginask) {
          $("#validationmessages").after('<div class="col-sm-12 alert"><a href="javascript:;" id="loginpop" class="btn btn-primary">login</a></div>');}
          $("#loginpop").click(function(){
            //alert('ok');
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
            $('input[name="tinsignup"]')[0].focus();
          });
        }

        //setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessages').fadeOut();} , 4000);



      }

       }); 
    });
     $("#signbut").click(function(){
       //$("#validationmessignin").hide();
          $("#validationmessignin").html("<img src='img/Preloader_11.gif' alt='loading'/> <b>Please wait...</b>");
          var dataString =  $("#signinform").serialize();
      $.ajax({     
         url:"processing/login_verify.php",
           type:"POST",
           dataType:"json",
           data:dataString,
           cache: false, 
           success: function(response)
       {
       if(response.successvalue)
       {
        //$("#validationmessignin").attr("class","alert alert-success");
        $("#validationmessignin").html("<i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-fw fa-lg'></i>"+response.responsemessage+"");
        $('#validationmessignin').fadeIn();
        setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessignin').fadeOut();} , 1000);
        setTimeout( function(){window.location='altair/index.php';} , 1000);
       }
       else if (response.successvalueverifyotp) 
       {
        window.location='verify.php';
       }
       else
       {
        $("#validationmessignin").html(response.responsemessage);
        $('#validationmessignin').fadeIn();
        setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessignin').fadeOut();} , 3000); 
        }

      }

       }); 
    });
     $("#forpassbut").click(function(){
      //$("#validationmessignin").hide();
          $("#validationmessignin").html("<img src='img/Preloader_11.gif' alt='loading'/> <b>Please wait...</b>");
          var dataStringforgot =  $("#signinform").serialize();
      $.ajax({     
         url:"processing/forgot_password.php",
           type:"POST",
           dataType:"json",
           data:dataStringforgot,
           cache: false, 
           success: function(response)
       {
       if(response.successvalue)
       {
        //$("#validationmessignin").attr("class","alert alert-success");
        $("#validationmessignin").html("<i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-fw fa-lg'></i>"+response.responsemessage+"");
        $('#validationmessignin').fadeIn();
        setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessignin').fadeOut();} , 3000);
        //setTimeout( function(){window.location='index.php';} , 1000);


       }
       else
       {

        //$("#validationmessignin").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
        $("#validationmessignin").html(response.responsemessage);
        $('#validationmessignin').fadeIn();
        setTimeout( function(){$('#validationmessignin').fadeOut();} , 3000);



        }


      }

       }); 
    });      









});
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a database access issue.  Check the credentials and grants for the user on the database.

Comment: there is not credentials and grants issue cause all query run perfect

Comment: what about database connection. did you change the parameters as per live.

Comment: Did you create the database schema and load any data?

Comment: i have change and update my new database connection but not working

Comment: and i didn't create any database schema and load data

Comment: [link](http://grabbizz.com) try to registration

Comment: <?php
 session_start();
 require_once('databaseconfiguration.php');
 class Databaseconnection
 {
  var $databaselink;
  function __construct()
  {
   $this->databaselink = '';
   $this->databaselink = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
   $this->databaselink->query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
   mb_language('uni');
   mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
   $this->databaselink->query("set names 'utf8'");
  }
 }
?> this is database connection file